# Ndepend find all references of assemblies?

Tags: ndepend

I am using Ndepend to find out what third party DLL's are needed for my application
This is a screenshot of missing dependencies. From the right side of the screenshot there are some red x's. Can someone help me or point me to where I could find **'Why is this DLL needed? Or which assembly references these. Find all  the references for these missing dependencies'**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This not found DLL (in the blue grid, third-party assembly) is needed because it is referenced by a DLL in the green grid (application assemblies).

If you run the analysis from there, you'll get warning logs like `assembly XYZ is referencing DevExpress.ExpressApp.v.. version ABC that cannot be found`.

You can unfold the *Directories manager* just above the green grid, to add folder(s) that contain the DLLs not found.

[image: NDepend project folders of assemblies]